# OpenGL types GLint, Glbyte... to C++ int32_t, int8_t... mapping

Tags: c++, opengl, types

OpenGL specification says that all types has fixed bitdepths. Also as I know c++ specification doesn't regulate bitdepth. There is only thing that we know: c++ types like int32_t, int16_t,... contains need number of bytes, but not bits. How we can safely use these types? And how can we be sure that say OpenGL type "unsigned integer" will match with uint32_t at binary representation level?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the safety you're looking for? You mean how can you safely go out of your way by storing e.g. a `GLuint` in a non-GL type, and do so safely? (... as you've got some sort of step, maybe serialisation or something like that, which can accept only the built-in types?)

Comment: For example variable int8_t i = 99; has bits image 0001001. Then we introduce GLbyte u = i; and send it to the shader. Why opengl must interpret this number correctly in the shader as 99?

Comment: `And how can we be sure that say OpenGL type "unsigned integer" will match with uint32_t at binary representation level?` OpenGL requires GLuint to be 32 bits large. And it would make almost zero sense for a system to have 2 different ints of same size, but different byte order.

Comment: At the same system yes. But defferent CPU may differently encode integers. I mean not only the various orders of bytes but absolutely other method to encode integers.

Answer (score 2):

> There is only thing that we know: c++ types like int32_t, int16_t,... contains need number of bytes, but not bits.

That's not true at all. The C standard, which the C++ standard imports, states:

> The typedef name int*N*_t designates a signed integer type with width *N*, no padding bits, ...

N being the number of *bits*, not the number of bytes.

The OpenGL standard similarly defines its types with an exact number of bits, not bytes. Neither one allows padding.

Therefore, `GLuint` must be identically sized and formatted relative to `uint32_t`. They need not be the exact same type, but since they store the same range of values and have the same size, conversion between them ought to be lossless.

So it's not clear what you're concerned about.